# jenkind build from dockerfile appear docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235

Tags: docker, jenkins

When I build the job from my Dockerfile in Jenkins
I got the error like "docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235" when the console try to exec the docker images.

My Jenkins is built by Dockerfile. Reference is https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-building-docker-image-and-sending-to-registry-64b84ea45ee9.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install docker-ce
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce
RUN usermod -a -G docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

My Jenkins output like the below. The error is return after succeed build the images.

```
Successfully built b9afd9ecb148
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Integration-Es-Contracts\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory".
FATAL: Failed to run docker image
```

Comment: Does "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Integration-Es-Contracts" exist? Does Jenkins user have permissions to "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Integration-Es-Contracts"? What command line did you start the container? Did you create volume for Jenkins? I think you should first of all check if path is existing and Jenkis user has permission for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the issue is related to the permissions.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue is related to the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a runner inside a Group Runners in GitLab (runners in my computer).
The problem was disk full in that runner.